# Working with ListView in C++

Tags: c++, listview, mfc, visual-studio-2005

I got a stupid question on *ListView Control* usage.
I created a Windows Form App in VS2005. No I dragged a ListView Control from the toolbox. I want to implement my code to show some content(including both columns and rows). 
I know a little of MFC knowledge. I am not sure I must study the past MFC CListCtrol knowledge to implement my application or I can just study the `System.Windows.Forms::ListView` simply.

I found a good sample working with ListView (but wrote in C#). Can I translate the sample code from C# to C++ in VS2005? If I can. Could you please give me some suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class ListView1 : Form {
  ListView listView = new ListView();

  public ListView1() {
    listView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    PopulateListView();
    this.Controls.Add(listView);
    this.ClientSize = new Size(400, 200);
  }


  private void PopulateListView() {
    // Set the view to show details.
    listView.View = View.Details;

    // Add columns
    listView.Columns.Add("Author", 
                         -2, 
                         HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    listView.Columns.Add("Title", 
                         -2, 
                         HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView.Columns.Add("Price", 
                         -2, 
                         HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    // Add items
    ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("Steve Martin");
    item1.SubItems.Add("Programming .NET");
    item1.SubItems.Add("39.95");

    ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("Irene Suzuki");
    item2.SubItems.Add("VB.NET Core Studies");
    item2.SubItems.Add("69.95");

    ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("Ricky Ericsson");
    item3.SubItems.Add("Passing Your .NET Exams");
    item3.SubItems.Add("19.95");

    // Add the items to the ListView.
    listView.Items.AddRange(
                            new ListViewItem[] {item1, 
                                                item2, 
                                                item3}
                            );
  }

  public static void Main() {
    ListView1 form = new ListView1();
    Application.Run(form);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need that much of your previous knowledge of MFC to implement ListView. C++ under .NET (in layman terms means WinForm applications), you can almost seamlessly translate C# code to C++. If I understood your question correctly, what you need to do is to make sure how objects and properties are accessed in C++ if you are developing a winforms app. Like in C# if you have Object.function, in C++ you may need to write Object::function, this is just an example. Definitely you would need to some more in depth knowledge to run things seamlessly.

Comment: I thought I made a mistake at the design stage. I wonder to create a application with VS2005. The app must contain some GUI forms. That's why I create a WinForm application. But I thought the App must can run in some computers with or without .NET. Based on this requirement, I think I must recreate a new App with an MFC application template instead of my Win Form App.

Comment: @Nano, it sounds like you've created a .NET application in C++, so of course it will depend on the .NET framework being installed. I think you're correct about needing to recreate the app as MFC, but I'd choose to statically link MFC into the application rather than creating another dependency on the MFC DLL.

Comment: @Mark Ransom. Thanks for your suggestion too. I am googling *statically link MFC into the application*. :-)

Comment: @Nano, well Mark Ransom is right, just statically link MFC is the right way to go. All dependencies will end up being grouped into your project instead of later on providing separate files to remove the dependencies problems your program would be deployed.